# How to view Crystal Report without CrystalReportViewer?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a web application where I just need to view my report embedded in a web page. I don't want **CrystalReportViewer** side controls like printing, zooming, paging etc. Its look and feel should be like a scanned document picture. Any help?

Comment: how about generate a PDF?

Comment: Good idea. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Here's a code snippet that converts the crystal report object (in memory stream) to Pdf, Word, or Excel.

```
        using CrystalDecisions.Web;
        using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
        using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
        string path2 =  path + reportName;
        rpt.Load(path2);
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Database crDatabase = rpt.Database;
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = server;
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = db;
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = crystalUser;
        crConnectionInfo.Password = pwd;
        crConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

        <<<<<<report logic here>>>>>>>>>>>

        CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType typ = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
        if (exportFormatType == "doc")
            typ = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.WordForWindows;
        if (exportFormatType == "xls")
            typ = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Excel;

        MemoryStream ms = (MemoryStream)rpt.ExportToStream(typ);
```

Comment: Although you forgot to mention **<iframe>** after exporting it to pdf. but I will consider it my answer. Thanks.